# Can't make jQuery-Cascade generate second dropdownlist

Tags: php, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu, yii, yii-extensions

I have searched hard on google, forums and the documentation trying to avoid asking here, but I couldn't find a solution.

I have installed the [jQuery-Cascade Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jquery-cascade/).

In the View I have

```
<?php
    $divipola = $this->createWidget('ext.jquery-cascade.jQueryCascade');

// dropDownList($id, $selected, $data, $htmlOptions = array(), $source, $cascaded)
    echo $divipola->dropDownList('depto_dane',
            '', 
            CHtml::listData(Codigodane::model()->findAll(), 'depto_dane', 'depto_dane'),
            '', 
            CController::createUrl('codigodane/list'), 
            'muni_dane'.
            ''
    );
                echo Yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($divipola), 'vardump');


    ?>
```

In the Controller:

```
public function actionList() {
        echo Yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString('Entrando a actionList'), 'vardump');
        if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
            $queryvar = "";
            $queryvar.="depto_dane='";
            $queryvar.=$_GET['selected'];
            $queryvar.="'";
            $registro = Codigodane::model()->findAll($queryvar);
            $munis = array();
            echo Yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($registro), 'vardump');

            foreach ($registro as $muni) {
                echo Yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($muni), 'vardump');

                $munis[] = array('label' => $muni->muni_dane, 'value' => $muni->codigodane);
            }

            echo json_encode($munis);
            Yii::app()->end();
        } else {
            throw new CHttpException(400, 'Invalid request.');
        }
    }
```

The code seems to be working fine, the first dropdownlist is flawlessly rendered, and when I select an option it successfully retrieves an array from the model exactly as I need it (which I can see in firebug):

```
[{"label":"FLORENCIA","value":"18001"},{"label":"ALBANIA","value":"18029"},{"label":"BELEN DE LOS ANDAQUIES","value":"18094"},{"label":"CARTAGENA DEL CHAIRA","value":"18150"},{"label":"CURILLO","value":"18205"},{"label":"EL DONCELLO","value":"18247"},{"label":"EL PAUJIL","value":"18256"},{"label":"MONTA\u00d1ITA","value":"18410"},{"label":"MILAN","value":"18460"},{"label":"MORELIA","value":"18479"},{"label":"PUERTO RICO","value":"18592"},{"label":"SAN JOSE DEL FRAGUA","value":"18610"},{"label":"SAN VICENTE DEL CAGUAN","value":"18753"},{"label":"SOLANO","value":"18756"},{"label":"SOLITA","value":"18785"},{"label":"VALPARAISO","value":"18860"}]
```

What I dont know is how to use this array to create another dropdownlist or if (as I think) the extension should create the other dropdownlist with ID 'muni_dane'.

Am I doing something wrong? or maybe I missed something from the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an empty dropdownlist . The extension doesnt create one by itself. Add the following code to your view

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('muni_dane','',array(),array('id'=>'muni_dane'));
```